# Get List of SyndEntry instead of one SyndEntry object at a time in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want RssFeed adapter to give list of objects but it is producing one object at a time. How to get multiple object? Is it possible if i can buffer those objects and create list of it and then send it forward for further process?

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class RSSFeedFlow {

    @Value("https://www.aljazeera.com/xml/rss/all.xml")
    private Resource feedResource;

    @Bean
    public MetadataStore metadataStore() {
        PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore metadataStore = new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
        metadataStore.setBaseDirectory("src/main/resources");
        return metadataStore;
    }

    public MessageChannel outputChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow rssFeedFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Feed.inboundAdapter(feedResource, "feedTest")
                .metadataStore(metadataStore()), spec -> spec.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(5)))
                .channel("outputChannel")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow print() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("outputChannel")
                .handle(message -> {
                    SyndEntry syndEntry = (SyndEntry) message.getPayload();
                    System.out.println(syndEntry.getLink());
                })
                .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Feed.inboundAdapter()` is based on the `FeedEntryMessageSource`. See its JavaDoc:

```
 * This implementation of {@link org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource} will
 * produce individual {@link SyndEntry}s for a feed identified with the 'feedUrl'
 * attribute.
```

So, it is really an expected behavior to have `SyndFeed` scattered to its entries.

You can consider to aggregate several entries into some list using an aggregator endpoint: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator

Or you can consider to implement your own message source. Something like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow rssFeedFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(() -> new SyndFeedInput().build(new XmlReader(this.feedResource.getInputStream())),
                spec -> spec.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(5)))
                .channel("outputChannel")
                .get();
    }
```

The point of individual entries emission that `FeedEntryMessageSource` does some other logic like caching and filtering. Therefore it doesn't bring too much value for the framework to have a plain `SyndFeed` producer which may get the same data on every single polling cycle.